# How to set up nameserver for my static IP with DynDNS?

Tags: domain, domain-name-system

I'm having trouble trying to get my VPS IP work with my domain. I have no idea how to set up nameservers for my domain. I've put in my VPS IP into  DynDNS, but I've got the nameservers of DynDNS which are:

```
ns1.mydyndns.org
ns2.mydyndns.org
```

And added it to my domian registrar:

[image]

It's been 4 days since the DNS for "propagating" which still hasn't worked, when accessing to my domain it fails to load saying server could not be found.

I've entered the IP address of my VPS into my domain registrar:

[image]

I'm still wondering why it isn't working.

**EDIT**: The domain is `~` with an IP address of `~`.

Comment: Maybe if you let us know the actual domain and IP we can help better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using Dyndns to host your DNS and not merely be a secondary or tertiary provider.  You should use one of the features that comes with their DNS service, dynamic host entries.  When you set up the record for your host give it any IP address, also set the entry to have a TTL of 60 seconds.  At this point the address does not matter, just as long as it's an A record.  Next on your host run the dyndns client.  Configure the client to change it's DNS entry in your domain.  There is no need to get one of the dynamic domains.

I do this at home with my Netscreen firewall which is connected to a cable modem, and it works great.  The maximum downtime I can expect is 60 seconds which is the time it takes for the previous DNS entry to expire should it have recently been queried.

Answer (score 1):

If you've delegated your name servers to DynDNS then you should be creating your A, CNAME, MX, etc. records there, not at the registrar. My recommendation would be to check your WHOIS information and check your registrar to see which name servers are listed for your domain and go from there. As Chopper3 said, if you give us the actual domain name we can be a lot more helpful to you.

Comment: Based on what I'm seeing in a DNS report at dnsstuff.com, your name servers as listed by the parent name servers are ns1.mydyndns.org and ns1.mydyndns.org. The problem is that ns1.mydyndns.org and ns2.mydyndns.org don't have records for your domain and aren't answering authoratatively for your domain. So as I stated in my answer it looks like you need to delegate your name servers to DynDNS. It's not enough to "point" to DynDNS from your registrar, DynDNS needs to know that they should be authoratative for your domain, which is accomplished via delegation.

Comment: How can I do this in DynDNS?

Answer (score 0):

Does your VPS come with a static IP?

If it does, you do not need any dynamic dns support. All that you need to do is to set your domain registrar's DNS servers as your primary and secondary authoritative DNS server. Then, set your A-records within your domain registrar's configuration.

If it does not, you will need to install a dynamic dns client on your VPS to update its dynamic IP whenever it changes. Then, set the primary and secondary authoritative DNS servers to those of your dynamic dns provider.